# I was trying to create a video out of a numpy array but i was getting an error

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I was trying to create a video from a NumPy array, but i was getting this error all the time:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) c:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.simd_helpers.hpp:94: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function '__thiscall cv::impl::`anonymous-namespace'::CvtHelper<struct cv::impl::`anonymous namespace'::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<3,4,-1>,struct cv::impl::A0xe227985e::Set<0,2,5>,2>::CvtHelper(const class cv::_InputArray &,const class cv::_OutputArray &,int)'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 4 (CV_32S)
```

Link to the full code - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qqat43eJw0Ql46TlFRiGMjqROs2QjCFj/view?usp=sharing

Here is the structure of the code:

```
import cv2 , time , numpy
frame = numpy.asarray(the long list of NumPy array, if you want, it is in the link above)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mp4v' , fourcc , 20.0 , (640 , 480))
out.write(frame)
out.release()
```

If I added a frame = frame.astype(numpy.uint8) before it, then a video was created but it was actually a video of just 1 photo of the first frame!!!!

Please help me out with this. It would really mean a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am only able to find a single RGB image in your link. Do you want to make a video with that single image of dimension 640x480x3? If you can ensure that the frame array here has multiple RGB images the following code should be enough:

```
import cv2 , time , numpy
frame = numpy.asarray(the long list of NumPy array, if you want, it is in the link above)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
writer = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi', fourcc, 1, (frame_height, frame_width)) 
i=0
for img in (frame):
    print("writing frame # {}".format(i))
    writer.write(img.astype('uint8'))
    i+=1

writer.release()
```

Comment: Thank You so much. I noticed my mistake. Please see my latest question as well.